# SQL server 2012 wont load CLR 4.0 assembles

Tags: sql-server-2012, .net-assembly, clr4.0

I just upgraded to SQL Server 2012 with SP1 because I could not load CLR assemblies from .net 4.0. Now I have both 2008 and 2012 running on my VM. Im trying to load the assemblies into 2012 but I still get the same unsupported version errors. when i run the following query, 
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties

I only see the version 2.0.50727. Prior to the upgrade, i installed .net 4.0. How do I get SQL to use .net 4.0 when loading assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

Check this key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\OnlyUseLatestCLR
```

is it 0 or 1

If it is 0 - change to 1 and reboot your machine. Should help.

OR

try to simply disable and enable SQL CLR on SQL2012. Or try to disable both (SQL2008 and SQl2012) and then enable only SQl2012

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

OR

you may try to force SQL Server to load .NET 4.0 runtime by creating `sqlservr.exe.config` file in the `Binn` folder with next configuration

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <requiredRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```